# Для чего используют ключевое слово final?

Tags: java, ооп

Встретил один проект в котором практически все переменные инициализированы через ключевое слово `final` . Значение и функцию этого слова я знаю, вопрос в том, какой смысл все переменные так инициализировать? Это как то сказывается на производительности?

Comment: кто-то просто загоняется))

Comment: не вовсех слуяаях  это как-то влияет на производительность.  я не виде л прмой зависимости  между final   искоростью  работы    программы  и старина  Скотт Оукс   тоже об этом  не пишет

Comment: На производительности это вряд ли сказывается. Необходимо привести пример, где производительность падает. Смысл как раз в том, что значение этого слова надо использовать там, где это необходимо, в противном случае придется в будущем делать рефакторинг и убирать этот модификатор с переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл может быть в том, чтобы сделать все объекты неизменяемыми/иммутабельными, то есть, внутреннее состояние объекта не может меняться, может только генерироваться новый объект.

Следовательно, такие объекты являются потокобезопасными (thread-safe), и с ними проще работать в многопоточных приложениях.  В частности, можно избежать использования синхронизации при доступе к таким объектам, что и приводит к выигрышу в производительности.

Comment: поддерживаю этот ответ. Kotlin, например, как раз построен на разделение на изменяемые и неизменяемые переменные. похоже, что кто-то решил загнаться и воплотить эту идею на Java через final.